# SingleView application change view from code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have such storyboard in order to have a nabber with burger menu:

[image]

All works fine with navigation and showing the menu.

In my ViewController i have next code:

```
if([navManager.CurrentViewName isEqual:@"Login"])
    {
        // TODO: Show login view
    }
```

**I want to show Login view inside the red ( highlighted ) rectangle. What would be the best solution to achieve this? I will have many other views - Login, Help, Profile etc. and all them i want to show in that red rectangle.**

I have tried to create a LoginViewController on the storyboard for login and use it like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:login.view]
```

but it covered up the whole view, but i need that nabber to be always visible.

I have tried to add separate view control to the ViewController and do so:

```
self.ContentView = login.view
```

But it had some strange offset ( the view wasn't centered ).

Here is my storyboard with LoginViewController on the right ( for test purposes it has a slider on the middle ):

[image]

The highlighted Contetn is where i want to paste my controllers.

So i have this code:

```
if([navManager.CurrentViewName isEqual:@"Login"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LoginController *controller = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];
        controller.view.frame = self.Content.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
    }
```

And the result is:

[image]

**Why there is an offset?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to achieve the purpose.

```
login.view.frame = frame of red rectangle   
[self.view addSubview:login.view];
[self addChildViewController:login];
```

Comment: @Cheese- It's happening because you need to add appropriate constraints on UI Elements, as the view in Storyboard is in ANY ANY mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different xib's file like for login,help and profile.And which ever view is need you can initiate and add to Viewcontroller view as

```
let loginView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LoginView", owner: self, options: nil) as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0) as? LoginView

        loginView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
```

You can change xib view size whatever you want and this practice will make to keep code clean as your viewcontroller will not get crowded with different view logic like login,help and profile.Each view logic will in their xib's class file.

Comment: You are using size classes and you had not set any autolayout constraint.Either add autolayout constraint to each elements in view controller or change size to any iphone by clicking on attributes Inspector -> simulated Metrics -> size -> iphone 4.5 inches(example)